# Two Sum LeetCode Java Questions

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am attempting a Java mock interview on LeetCode. I have the following problem:

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

```
Example:

Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].
```

I was attempting to implement a recursive solution. However, I am receiving errors upon trying to run my code.

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int[] sumnums = nums.clone();
        //int[2] sol = {0,1};
        int[] sol = new int[]{0,1};

        sol = new int[2];
        int j=sumnums.length;
        int t=target;

        for(int i=0;i<sumnums.length;i++){
            if ((sumnums[i]+sumnums[j])==t){
                sol[0]=i;
                sol[1]=j;
                //return sol;
            }
        }
        j=j-1;
        twoSum(sumnums,t);
        return sol;

    }
}
```

Error(s):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at Solution.twoSum(Solution.java:12)
    at __DriverSolution__.__helper__(__Driver__.java:8)
    at __Driver__.main(__Driver__.java:54)
```

It appears to me the error may have to do with the following line of code:

```
if ((sumnums[i]+sumnums[j])==t){
```

Therefore, I am wondering if this is a syntax related error. I am attempting to check to see if two numbers add up to a different number.

Since this is a naive attempt at a recursive solution, I am happy to take any other criticism. But I am mostly concerned with getting my attempt at this problem to work and run with all testcases.

Thanks.

Comment: `sumnums.length` will be 2, while the only existing indexes are 0 and 1. You probably meant to do `int j = sumnums.length - 1`

Comment: Thanks. An oversight on my part. At least that solves that issue I'm having.

Answer (score 4):

**METHOD 1. Naive approach: Use two for loops**
The naive approach is to just use two nested for loops and check if the sum of any two elements in the array is equal to the given target.

**Time complexity: O(n^2)**

```
 // Time complexity: O(n^2)
private static int[] findTwoSum_BruteForce(int[] nums, int target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                return new int[] { i, j };
            }
        }
    }
    return new int[] {};
}
```

**METHOD 2. Use a HashMap (Most efficient)**
You can use a HashMap to solve the problem in O(n) time complexity. Here are the steps:

Initialize an empty HashMap.
Iterate over the elements of the array.
For every element in the array -
If the element exists in the Map, then check if it’s the complement (target - element) also exists in the Map or not. If the complement exists then return the indices of the current element and the complement.
Otherwise, put the element in the Map, and move to the next iteration.
**Time complexity: O(n)**

```
 // Time complexity: O(n)
private static int[] findTwoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> numMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int complement = target - nums[i];
        if (numMap.containsKey(complement)) {
            return new int[] { numMap.get(complement), i };
        } else {
            numMap.put(nums[i], i);
        }
    }
    return new int[] {};
}
```

**METHOD 3. Use Sorting along with the two-pointer sliding window approach**
There is another approach which works when you need to return the numbers instead of their indexes. Here is how it works:

Sort the array.
Initialize two variables, one pointing to the beginning of the array (left) and another pointing to the end of the array (right).
Loop until left < right, and for each iteration

> if arr[left] + arr[right] == target, then return the indices.
> if arr[left] + arr[right] < target, increment the left index.

else, decrement the right index.
This approach is called the two-pointer sliding window approach. It is a very common pattern for solving array related problems.

Time complexity: O(n*log(n))

```
 // Time complexity: O(n*log(n))
private static int[] findTwoSum_Sorting(int[] nums, int target) {
    Arrays.sort(nums);
    int left = 0;
    int right = nums.length - 1;
    while(left < right) {
        if(nums[left] + nums[right] == target) {
            return new int[] {nums[left], nums[right]};
        } else if (nums[left] + nums[right] < target) {
            left++;
        } else {
            right--;
        }
    }
    return new int[] {};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a HashMap? Here is how it will work. We will iterate through the array and check if the `target - nums[i]` exists in the map. If not, we will store `Key, Value` as the number and its index respectively i.e `K = nums[i], V = i`

Here is how it will work: 
Consider `nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9`

We will start iterating the array

First comes 2. Here we will check ( 9 - 2 ) i.e 7 does not exist in the hashmap, so we will store 2 as key and its index 0 as its value

Then, comes 7. Here we will check ( 9 - 7 ) i.e 2 which exists in the map and so we will return the index of 2 and index of 7 i.e returning [ 0, 1 ]

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {

        HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
         for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) 
         {
             if(map.containsKey(target - nums[i])) 
             {
                 return new int[] {map.get(target-nums[i]),i};

             }
             else
                 map.put(nums[i],i);
         }
         return new int[] {-1,-1};
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned
First comes 2. Here we will check ( 9 - 2 ) i.e 7 does not exist in the hashmap

actually **7** does exist in the HashMap right
nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int[] sumnums = nums.clone();
        //int[2] sol = {0,1};
        int[] sol = new int[]{0,1};

        sol = new int[2];
        int j=sumnums.length; // Every recursion j will be initialized as sumnums.length instead of J-1
        int t=target;

        for(int i=0;i<sumnums.length;i++){
           // if ((sumnums[i]+sumnums[j])==t){  
           // Remember that Java arrays start at index 0, so this value(sumnums[j]) is not exist in the array.
              if ((sumnums[i]+sumnums[j-1])==t){
                sol[0]=i;
                sol[1]=j;
                return sol;
            }
        }
        j=j-1;
        twoSum(sumnums,t);
        return sol;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the many possible solutions:

```
public class TwoSumIndex {
    public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] arr = {2, 7, 11, 15, 9, 0, 2, 7};
        System.out.println(findTwoSums(arr, 9));
    }

    private static List<List<Integer>> findTwoSums(int[] arr, int target) {
        Set<Integer> theSet = Arrays.stream(arr).mapToObj(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        List<Integer> arrList = Arrays.stream(arr).mapToObj(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> theList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> added = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int a = target - arr[i];
            if (theSet.contains(a) && added.indexOf(i) < 0) { // avoid duplicates;
                Integer theOther = arrList.indexOf(a);
                theList.add(new Pair(i, theOther));
                added.add(i);
                added.add(theOther);
            }
        }
        return theList.stream().map(pair -> new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

There are several things you need to know:

1. **duplicates** in the input array are allowed;
2. un-ordered array in the input is allowed;
3. no index pair duplicate in the output;
4. time complexity is theoretically `O(N^2)` but actually will be much lower since `theSet.contains(a)` O(logN) will filter out all **failed** indexes and then do the *index duplicate* O(N) checking, so the actual time complexity should be `O(NlogN)`;

The output for the demo:

```
[[0, 1], [4, 5], [6, 1], [7, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the simpler approch

class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {

```
     int[] indices= new int[2];
    int len=nums.length;
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){

            for(int j=i+1; j<len;j++){         

                if((nums[i]+nums[j])==target){
                    indices[0] = i;
                    indices[1] = j;
                    return indices;

                }
            }


    }
     return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
    Complete code for beginners
     //Predefined values
    import java.util.Arrays;
    
    public class TwoSum {
    
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Solution solution = new Solution();
            int target = 9;
            int num[] = {2, 7, 11, 15};
            num = solution.twoSum(num, target);
    
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
        }
    }
    
    class Solution {
    
        public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
            int result[] = new int[2];
            int sum;
            for (int i = 0; i + 1 < nums.length; i++) {
                // adding the alternate numbers
                sum = nums[i] + nums[i + 1];
    
                if (sum == target) {
                    result[0] = i;
                    result[1] = i + 1;
                    return result;
    
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }





************************************************************************
//User-defined

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author shelc
 */
public class TwoSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Solution solution = new Solution();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n;
        System.out.print("Enter the number of elements : ");
        n = scanner.nextInt();

        int array[] = new int[10];
        System.out.println("Enter the array elemets : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        int target;
        System.out.println("Enter the target : ");
        target = scanner.nextInt();

        int nums[] = solution.twoSum(array, target);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));

    }

}

class Solution {

    public int[] twoSum(int nums[], int target) {

        int result[] = new int[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if ((nums[i] + nums[j]) == target) {
                    result[0] = i;
                    result[1] = j;
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int[] arr = new int[2];
        int arrIndex =0;
        for(int i =0; i<nums.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<nums.length-1;j++){
                if( i!=j) {// don't check to itself
                    if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                        arr[arrIndex] = i;
                        arr[arrIndex + 1] = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Arrays.sort(arr);
     return arr; 
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).